# Are there general circuits that differentiate/integrate empirically?

Tags: electric-circuits, integration, differentiation

Is it possible to construct simple circuits, that given a time-varying input, produce an output that represents the derivative or integral of the input with respect to time?

Comment: Is it necessary that the circuit is somehow made up of "simple" components? Otherwise, yes, computers can certainly do this.

Comment: Yes my initial edit of the question had (not computers) in brackets.  I'm after a very simple circuit involving resistors, capacitors and transistors.  I know "simple" is subjective, so I'm happy for one to find the simplest circuit they can that allows for this.

Comment: @DavidM.R., can computers do this without employing algorithms with discrete time steps?  How?  I'm after a non digital circuit that solves the differentiation/integration empirically and exactly.

Comment: Start browsing for Analog Computers on the internet. Try "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently what you are looking for is called an "Integrator" and a "Differentiator". (I'm not too good with circuits, so I can't judge if these are simple enough.)

See e.g. http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_8/11.html

Comment: have also a look at analogue computers, built up with these as building blocks.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogue_computer . when i started in physics they were compeiting with digital.

Answer (score 4):

As David pointed out in his answer, the circuits are called the differentiator and the integrator respectively. They use [operational amplifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) (op amps) to do this.

An op-amp isn't necessarily a "simple circuit" to build, since it consists of several transistors and hundreds of resistors and capacitors, but since it's extremely easily available as an [IC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit), it's plenty easy to build an [integrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrator) or a [differentiator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiator) circuit.

Comment: Back in my grandfather's day, of course, the amps were tube devices and you could do the same things with them. And they did.

Comment: RC circuit integrates the current